# Filtering against canEdit in Calendars returns inverted results

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, outlook-restapi

I'm using the list calendars endpoint described [here](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/user_list_calendars). When applying a `$filter` against the `canEdit` property, the results are the exact opposite of the filter criteria.

When I call:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/calendars?$filter=canEdit eq false
```

It returns Calendars where `canEdit = true`.

If I call the opposite:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/calendars?$filter=canEdit eq true
```

It returns the calendars where `canEdit = false`.

Comment: I've been able to replicate this issue and logged a bug in the GitHub repository for this: https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/issues/2710.

Answer (score 1):

This issue appears to have been "fixed" on the date of this post (2022-05-18). The filter now got inverted back to the "expected" behavior, though I'd imagine after such a long time this move would likely break existing apps out there.

Comment: Yup!  It sure did